# Pass an instance of a generic type as a parameter on a dynamic instance of a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, exception

I am trying to build a list of dynamic types that is actually of type `ExceptionLogCondition` which is a class that defines the type of exception that needs to be dismissed and an optional condition predicate for the specific exception type.

The problem is with passing the exception to the `IsConditionValid(T e)` method. I always get this exception:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'MvcApplication.ErrorLogCondition.IsConditionValid(Exceptions.AjaxOnlyViolationException)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Stacktrace:

> at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Exception )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)    at
>   CONCENTRA.MOS.MvcApplication.ErrorLog_Filtering(Object sender,
>   ExceptionFilterEventArgs e) in C:_teamprojects\Main\Source\Global.asax.cs:line
>   213    at Elmah.ErrorLogModule.OnFiltering(ExceptionFilterEventArgs
>   args)    at Elmah.ErrorLogModule.LogException(Exception e, HttpContext
>   context)    at Elmah.ErrorLogModule.OnError(Object sender, EventArgs
>   args)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()

Here's the code:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        var exceptionsToDismiss = new List<dynamic>() {
            new ErrorLogCondition<Exceptions.AjaxOnlyViolationException>(),
            new ErrorLogCondition<WebsiteException>(c => c.LogError == true)
        };

        foreach (var exd in exceptionsToDismiss)
        {
            if(((Type)exd.ExceptionType).Equals(e.Exception.GetBaseException().GetType()) &&
                exd.IsConditionValid(e.Exception.GetBaseException()))
                // The second condition fails even though the type is correct (see first if condition).
                e.Dismiss();
        }
    }
}

public class ErrorLogCondition<T> where T : Exception, new() { 
    public Type ExceptionType {get;set;}
    public Predicate<T> ExceptionTypeCondition { get; set; }

    public ErrorLogCondition() {
        ExceptionType = typeof(T);
    }

    public ErrorLogCondition(Predicate<T> c)
    {
        ExceptionType = typeof(T);
        ExceptionTypeCondition = c;
    }

    public bool IsConditionValid(T e)
    { 
        return ExceptionTypeCondition == null || ExceptionTypeCondition.Invoke(e);
    }
}
```

My gut feeling says I might be overdoing it a bit. So I am open to other suggestions. Nevertheless I would also like to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: You should probably make the setter for the `ExceptionType` property of `ErrorLogCondition` private: `public Type ExceptionType { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetBaseException()` returns an `Exception`, which is not what `IsConditionValid` can accept.  You have the moral equivalent of this code:

```
Exception baseExp = e.Exception.GetBaseException() //which is a AjaxOnlyViolation
IsConditionValid( baseExp);

//where isconditionvalid is:
bool IsConditionValid(AjaxOnlyViolation e) { }
```

It doesn't matter that the instance at runtime is an AjaxOnlyViolation at runtime - the compiler doesn't know that.  What matters is that it is declared as possible that it is *any* exception, and there is no implicit cast from `Exception` to `AjaxOnlyViolation`.  Therefore, error.

You need to tell the compiler;  You can either change IsConditionValid to accept an Exception, then cast it to a `T` inside that method, or cast it before calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

From the code provided I *deduct* that  `e.Exception.GetBaseException()` returns an instance of the type which is not castable to `AjaxOnlyViolationException` type.

Comment: If this were true, the first condition would fail and the second condition would never execute.

Comment: @Peter: yes, but your methid expects AjaxOnlyViolationException, but you pass a BASE type to it. You can not do upper cast.

Answer (score 1):

As `GetBaseException()` return type is `Exception`, no method `public bool IsConditionValid(Exception e)` can be found. You should provide a method with the `Exception` type in the signature.

Nevertheless, this might not be the better approach for performance concerns (see MSDN about dynamics).

But you could use a `List<Predicate<Exception>>` which would do the same kind of job while reducing the required lines of code to do it, IMHO.

Comment: I'll give the `List<Predicate<Exception>>` approach a go, sounds logical.